# Citrix and Remote Desktop session showing inconsistency after some time - Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, citrix, rdesktop

We have a lab server RDE becomes blank screen after sometime though it connects .
When we login , it just shows the blank desktop with nothing visible , just the wallpaper .
Citrix takes long time to connect and if it does ( it takes long time "checking credential " screen even ) , it will also show a similar blank screen . 
Can anyone suggest where/what to look for to trouble shoot this issue . 
Let me know if u want any further details .

The lab works well and fine when we do a reboot and then the same problem happens after an hour or so ...

Comment: What version of Citrix?

Answer (score 0):

See this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941158